# GIT SSL error persist despite recommended fix for Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, git, ssl, osx-yosemite

I continue to get the error: **SSL: certificate verification failed (result: 5) (128)** on Yosemite despite following all directions found online to fix it.

My current setup (HomeBrew) is:

```
$ php --version
PHP 5.5.20 (cli) (built: Jan 11 2015 20:00:36) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

$ curl --version
curl 7.37.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0) libcurl/7.37.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1k zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp

$ php -i | grep "SSL Version"
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.0.1
```

Am I missing something? When I set `sslVerify = false` the error changes to **SSL: CA certificate set, but certificate verification is disabled**. I already have the certificate in Key Chain and I can access it in the brower without problems.

I also tried:

```
$ gnutls-cli -p 7990 **.***.**.**
- Status: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown. 
*** PKI verification of server certificate failed...
*** Fatal error: Error in the certificate.
*** Handshake has failed
GnuTLS error: Error in the certificate.
```

EDIT:
Note that I've also edited my `.git > config` file in the repo to include the certificate exported from Firefox as such:

```
[http]
    sslCAInfo=/link/to/certificate.pem
```

Comment: "... despite following all directions found online to fix it." whatever these directions are. If you need help please clearly describe your setup and what you've tried and not in such vague terms.

Comment: Please read above. I've already included my setup and what I have tried. If any other specific information can be of further help, please ask, I'd be glad to provide it to you.

Comment: There are no information about the certificate you are using on your server. There are no information what you did to make the system trust the certificate.

Answer (score 3):

check your ~/.gitconfig file
I fixed my problem by temporarily removing the lines mentioning sslCAInfo and sslVerify.

then don't forget to add them later case the certificate is one that you are using it for something else.