# SSL verification problems trying to clone git repo with cocoapods

Tags: git, ssl, github, cocoapods, macos-sierra

I've just created a new Xcode 8 project and I'm trying to install Alamofire via CocoaPods.
Just after `pod install` I'm getting this error:

```
[!] Error installing Alamofire
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git /var/folders/18/n59jh6715l38t9wsmbgv5yvc0000gp/T/d20160926-3719-16da22u --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 4.0.1

Cloning into '/var/folders/18/n59jh6715l38t9wsmbgv5yvc0000gp/T/d20160926-3719-16da22u'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git/': SSL: certificate verification failed (result: 5)`
```

Last Friday I've installed another library into another Xcode 8 project with no problems at all, so I really don't know what to do.
In both cases I've used a Macbook Pro with MacOs Sierra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a similar ticket in [CocoaPods-app issue 355](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods-app/issues/355).

If it was working before and not now, something must be different between the two pod install instances. Either the user is not the same, or the url involved is different (ssh before vs. https now for instance)

As [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39712255/6309) or [in this issue](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/819#issuecomment-249693853), check your global git config (`~/.gitconfig`) and remove `slCAInfo` and `sslVerify` settings to see if the issue persists.
Or check if you [have an environment variable `SSL_CERT_FILE` currently active (exported)](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/49373#issuecomment-186576743). (also mentioned [in this issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/32019#issuecomment-180162137))

Try and see if using ssh works better:

```
git config --global url."git@github.com/Alamofire".insteadOf https://github.com/Alamofire
```

---

As the [OP Aleph72](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1331306/aleph72) commented [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699049/ssl-verification-problems-trying-to-clone-git-repo-with-cocoapods/39826936?noredirect=1#comment66949927_39826936):

> My slCAInfo line in the git config was pointing to an exported `.pem` file that included two certificates, and one of those expired few days ago.

So removing that sslCAinfo setting would help here.

Comment: The "suggested here" link helped me a lot. If I comment out the slCAInfo and sslVerify lines in my .gitconfig, then the pod install works as usual. I don't know why is that, but it works.

Comment: @Aleph72 probably because it falls back to the default system-wide ssl CA settings, which do include the right CA in order for the https tls connection to complete itself successfully.

Comment: Ok I got it now. My slCAInfo line in the git config was pointing to an exported .pem file that included *two* certificates, and one of those expired few days ago.

Comment: @Aleph72 Well spotted. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thanks @VonC, have to wait 19 hours to award the bounty.

Comment: @Aleph72 No problem. Glad you have resolved the issue.